# Is it possible to build monetdb/e as a static library?

Tags: monetdb

Is there an easy way to configure the monetdb cmake build to produce a monetdb/e static library?

Answer (score 2):

No, it only produces "dynamic" library.  Static libraries are not an option currently.

Comment: I think this would be really useful for the embedded use case

Comment: True, that probably makes more sense for an embedded DBMS.  Our first target is to produce the first major release of MonetDB/e asap. After that, we'll gradually add more features.

Comment: That sounds great!

Comment: Added this to the [wish list](https://github.com/MonetDBSolutions/MonetDBe-Python/issues/77).